# Hide a single record in Elastic Search on a per user basis

Tags: elasticsearch

As a logged in user, I want to be able to hide a single record that I never want to see again if I perform the same search. Is this possible with ElasticSearch?

I've read about multitenancy and filters but I'm not quite sure how a top level implementation might look like.

One of my ideas is that I store some reference to the unwanted record in an RDB and then add those references into a filter query but I'm not sure what reference to use since Elastic Search generates it's own ID's that may not stay the same when a re-index happens.

Comment: You can supply your own IDs for documents - just include the id field in the posted doc (or if you don't want to override the default ID you can always supply a unique identifier in a separate field). Your idea seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: do you do regular sync of your data from RDB to elastic, i suppose your RDB is primary database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you have not many users and not too big documents you can go with field on the document, Add field **dismissedBy** and when use dismiss write update to document

```
POST test/type1/1/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.dismissedBy.add(params.userId)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "userId" : "1"
        }
    }
}
```

And query:

```
POST /index/documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "dismissedBy": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem** with this approach is that if you re-index document all settings will be overwritten so you must keep copy in some other places too.

**Other option** if documents are large or you have lots of users then I would go with [parent/child approach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html)

If user hit dismiss then you should index it

```
PUT /indexname/dissmisses/1?parent=dismissforid
{
  "userId":  1
}
```

Then when you search you do

```
POST /index/documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "dissmiss",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "userId": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```